# Can you make an item inflict a status effect in vanilla Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I looked around and found how to make an item (in this case a sword) inflict a potion/status effect when it hits a mob, but all of them are in Java edition. Is there any way to do this in vanilla Bedrock using commands?

Comment: I don't think you can, iirc you need NBT tags for that and those don't work in Bedrock edition

Comment: just commands? unfortunately not possible. It is possible using behavior packs, as you can add a hit detection to the mobs you want this to work on that check for the player yielding a specific item (which itself needs to be checked using a player animation). But with just commands this is probably impossible.